# select distinct match data from "MYSQL" from duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have the following data in my database.

| TEAM1 | TEAM2 | WIN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | A |
| B | A | A |
| A | C | C |
| C | A | C |

As can be seen in the table, there are two records for one match, one where A plays B and one where B plays A, in both the matches winner is obviously A.
How can we get only a single record for every match?

**Required Output:**

| TEAM1 | TEAM2 | WIN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | A |
| A | C | C |

**SQL Fiddle Code:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `IPL` (
  `TEAM1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `TEAM2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `WIN` varchar(200) NOT NULL
)DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `IPL` (`TEAM1`, `TEAM2`, `WIN`) VALUES
  ('A', 'B', 'A'),
  ('B', 'A', 'A'),
  ('A', 'C', 'C'),
  ('C', 'A', 'C');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to after something as straightforward as this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(TEAM1,TEAM2) TEAM1
              , GREATEST(TEAM1,TEAM2) TEAM2
              , WIN 
           FROM ipl;
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick way to achieve this by selecting distinct rows after putting the teams in alphabetical order.

```
select distinct
  case when team1 < team2 then team1 else team2 end as "team1",
  case when team1 < team2 then team2 else team1 end as "team2",
  win
from ipl
```

Comment: Deneberg, this would work for the sample data that I have posted but I was looking for something more generic